# How to update client library logic in real time?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, client-server

I've mobile SDK (iOS/Android) integrated into many different native apps. Once thing I noticed was it is very hard to maintain it once it released out to market. I am looking for a good design that allow developers to update the logic/ fix bugs quickly.

Instead of going thru dev --> test --> release --> adoption period, there should be a better way to quick sync up the updated logic.

**For example, if my `v1.0` has this logic**

```
int adder(int a, int b){
  return a+b
}
```

and suddenly I want to do some input validation and update the logic to

```
int adder(int a, int b){
   return a+b+1 
}
```

following current releasing flow, i would have to go thru the entire release process and wait for all apps to adopt my new `v1.1` library (if I am lucky).

**I thought of few ideas,**

1. Remote config, for example, like **Firebase Remote config**. But this only allow me to tune the parameters, not really change any logic. At most, close this feature by having a flag to turn on and off it.
2. react native. I don't know how react native is going to help in this case since I am only a library, no UI involved.

Any other ideas?

Comment: is it a Cordova/ionic/phonegap based app ?

Comment: no they are all native platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 solutions, none is ideal though:

1. Make the treatment remote: Use a rest API to externalize your polymorphic operations. then you can update the API whenever you want and the application will follow - CONS: does not work if the phone is offline.
2. Do like cordova does. Having javascripts that are hosted and run locally in a hidden webview to get the results somehow (print the result raw in the body and read it from the native code). Your app, when online can check if a newer version of the script exists and download the update to adapt its behavior. Less easy than the number one but always works.

Comment: I don't really understand first option, what do you mean by using rest API to externalize? How to fetch say the polymorphic Java logic and make is compile at run time?

Comment: Let's say you would have a endpoint `adder` to stick your example. If your app is calling the endpoint to perform the addition, if you want to change this behavior, by changing the endpoint code the application by calling the new code will automatically follow the new logic.

Comment: I think this sort of answering the question. however the hidden webview might cause privacy concern. Given the power of javacsript running on webview. This can be so scary.

Comment: That's pretty safe, I mean the Javascript will not be able to access the "outside" world if not packaged with cordova and some plugins (which I don't think you need here). No access to the file system, the memory nor the app storage.